# Dynamically generate translatable columns using metadata

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to make a Translatable behavior for my entities using metadata.

I have a class Article

```
class Article implements TranslatableInterface {

/**
 * @HeidanTranslatable
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @HeidanLocale
 */
private $locale;


public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
}

public function getLocale() {
    return $this->locale;
}

public function setLocale($locale) {
    $this->locale = $locale;
    return $this;
}
```

I would like to have kind of Gedmo Doctrine Extension behavior which will create in database columns depending on property and allowed locales.

For example, with the entity article, I would like that two columns are created : title_fr, title_en.

I'd like this stuff is bridged to Doctrine behavior and I made a loadClassMetadataListener

```
class LoadClassMetadataListener {

/**
 * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
 */
public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $metadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

    $metadata
        ->mapField(array('fieldName' => 'title_fr', 'type' => 'text'))
    ;

}
```

When I run a doctrine:schema:update --force I have the following error :

[ReflectionException]
  Property Heidan\CoreBundle\Entity\Article::$title_fr does not exist

So I guess they said that the property title_fr does not exist, and that's right.

I do not want to set manually properties (private $title_fr, private $title_en, private $content_fr, private $content_en) for all my entities.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior so far ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't think `title_fr, title_en` is a good design.. why not simply use [DoctrineBehaviors from KnpLabs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors)?

Comment: I used to join with a dedicated Translation table all my objects but I did too many leftJoin which made a lot of performance issue (Sometimes I got until 16 leftJoin).

I also do not like to implement external bundles because I have external specification such as implementing Chinese and generating ZH Hanzi language slugs.

Comment: I didn't find any answer to my question, so I had to found another solution that is not what I expect but can do the work. I used PHP Traits (content_fr, content_en, content_zh AND content) + annotations (which field is translatable) + postLoad listeners which has the task to set the 'content' depending on locale.
Not the best way to do I think but it provides me flexibility and re-usability.